# How to calculate heartbeat with rgb and ir values in c# with kinect for windows

Tags: c#, kinect-v2

I am trying to calculate heartbeat with kinect for windows. I am getting rgb signals from kinect but i dont know how to use them to calculate heartbeat.

Here is an example signal:

```
MillisecondsElapsed,Blue,Green,Red,Alpha,Ir
90314,0.489540968250217,0.500007640762017,0.490331220386811,0.492362553339766,0.312132897434067
90378,0.489551480652564,0.500007640762017,0.490500391796487,0.492365905488138,0.311769126542914
90446,0.489342365232816,0.5,0.490341658993442,0.492299096068791,0.314740236447865
90709,0.489559386372135,0.500007640762017,0.490451999652075,0.492369182157095,0.311420592991154
90777,0.489512495286287,0.500007640762017,0.490370609868187,0.492395221031121,0.312435239765556
90846,0.492175687235476,0.489316761169419,0.500003678999775,0.490248794627907,0.314895148490442
90916,0.492151697259946,0.489342617291176,0.500003678999775,0.490206456377176,0.315459145693882
```

Answer (score 1):

The author of the orignal Kinect demo released his source as a C# library: https://github.com/dngoins/Kinectv2HeartRate . I suggest you use this library to achieve your goal.